# React not keeping order of elements passed as a component prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple modal component, where I would like to pass footer as a component:

```
export const ConfirmationModal = forwardRef(
    (
        {
            heading,
            description,
            footer,
        }: {
            heading: string;
            description: string;
            footer: ReactNode;
        },
        ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDialogElement>
    ) => {
        return (
            <Modal ref={ref} header={{ heading }} closeOnBackdropClick>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <BodyLong>{description}</BodyLong>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>{footer}</Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
);
```

But, when I pass the footer as a component:

```
               <ConfirmationModal
                    ref={ref}
                    description="Would you like to delete?"
                    heading="Would you like to delete?"
                    footer={
                        <>
                            <Button type="button" variant="secondary" onClick={() => ref.current?.close()}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                            <Button type="button" onClick={() => onRemoveBarn(index)}>
                                Delete
                            </Button>
                        </>
                    }
                />
```

If I do it like this then when I open the modal for some reason, button `delete` comes first and button `cancel` second. Why is order of the buttons changed, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML when inspecting the DOM in the browser?

Comment: its probably could be your styling or the component written in it. React doesn't modify the order unless you have told it so or you have set it somwhere

Answer (score 0):

You can change the priority of placing those buttons with the order style, for this their parent should get the style of display: flex.

```
<div style={{flex: 'flex'}}>
            <Button type="button" variant="secondary" onClick={() => ref.current?.close()}
            style={{order: '2'}}>
                Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button type="button" onClick={() => onRemoveBarn(index)}
            style={{order: '1'}}>
                Delete
            </Button>
        </div>
```